# How to get rid of a big space character encountered while concatenating multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the result I am getting while concatenating multiple columns, can anyone please check and let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image: Query and result]

I want my result in below format.

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `replace` function is replacing an empty string with an empty string.  Where you have `,'','')) AS combol` use `,' ','')) AS combol` instead and you should get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick for eliminating internal spaces:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, ' ', '><'), '<>', ''), '><', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you want to eliminate all spaces, right? If so:

```
result = replace(result,' ','') ;
```

will remove all blanks from `result`.

Comment: It is helpful too.